# Can't access this.props.navigator

Tags: react-native

I've been creating my views this way:

```
var SettingsView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.donePressed}>
          //left out styling code for simplicity
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  },

  donePressed: function() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  },
});
```

This is working fine. `donePressed` is an event handler that's hooked up with a `TouchableHighlight` in `render` (not shown).

Today I tried to refactor it to this:

```
class SettingsView extend React.Component {
  render() {
    //same stuff as above
  }

  donePressed() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }
}
```

This rendered the settings screen as normal. But when `donePressed` triggered, screen turned red saying they can't find `this.props.navigator`.

I'm not sure what is going on here, please help me out!

Edit:

This screen is brought up via another touch event handler from a different page via this method:

```
settingsTapped: function() {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'SettingsView',
    component: SettingsView,
  })
},
```

I've also tried to add `passProps: this.props.navigator` within `settingsTapped` too. What I'm most confused is why changing the way I create the class could suddenly make `this.props.navigator` invisible.

Comment: Can you show how donePressed is being called ? Also, is there a reference to your navigator passed down to the element you are in?

Comment: Hey Nader, thanks for commenting again. I've updated the post with what you've asked for. `donePressed` is called on the `TouchableHighlight` element `onPress`.

Comment: Have you tried onPress={ () => this.donePressed() } ?

Comment: It worked!? Care to explain what that did in an answer post? :] 

I'm confused why changing my way of declaring the class would hide `this.props.navigator` unless I have the event handling done your way.

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll do my best at describing why it works that way! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason it wasn't working is that because you are using Classes as opposed to the createClass function, `this` is no longer bound to the correct scope. You may need to use an es6 fat arrow function to get `this` lexically bound to the correct scope, like so:

```
onPress={ () => this.donePressed() }
```

You could also do this to get it to work:

```
onPress={ this.donePressed.bind(this) }
```